# Login Page not working, html

Tags: php, html, authentication, web

I am working on a website. but, i have a problem with it, when ever i fill in my login form, it gets stuck on the loading page. and doesn't seem to search the user list for registered users.

I'm new to this so, please bear with me.

Below is the LoginForm.php

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return 
   validate();" >
   <div>Username: </br><input type="text" name="user" /> </div>
   </br>
   <div>Password:  </br><input type="password" name="pass" /> </div>
   </br>
   <div><input type="submit" value="Login"  style="background-color: #1daa87; 
      border: none; color: black; padding: 8px 52px;"></input> <input 
      type="reset" value="Reset" style="background-color: #1daa87; border: none; 
      color: black; padding: 8px 52px;"></input></div>
</form>
```

Below is the login.php

```
    <?php
include_once ("dbconnection.php");

session_start(); //always start a session in the beginning

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
    if (empty($_GET['user']) || empty($_GET['pass'])) //Validating inputs using
    PHPcode
    {
    echo "Incorrect username or password";

    // header("location: LoginForm.php");//You will be sent to Login.php for re-

    login
    }

    $userName = $_GET["user"]; // as the method type in the form is "post" we
    areusing $_POSTotherwiseitwouldbe $_GET[]$password = $_GET["pass"];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT USER, PASS FROM WEBSITEUSERS WHERE USER = ?");

    // Fetching all the records with input credentials

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username); //You need to specify values to each '?'
    explicitly
    while usingpreparedstatements $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($UsernameDB, $PasswordDB); // Binding i.e. mapping
    databaseresultstonew variables

    // Compare if the database has username and password entered by the user.

    Passwordhastobedecrpted
    while comparing .
    if ($stmt->fetch() && password_verify($password, $PasswordDB))
        {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $userName; //Storing the username value in session
        variablesothatitcanberetrievedonotherpagesheader("location: userprofile.php"); // user will be taken to profile page
        }
      else
        {
        echo "<br />Incorrect username or password";
?>
    <br /><a href="LoginForm.php">Login</a>
    <?php
        }
}

?>
```

Below is the dbconnection.php

```
<?php
//Establishing connection with the database
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
    define('DB_NAME', ''); 
    define('DB_USER', ''); 
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');  
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'WebsiteUsers');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_NAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_USER);
?>
```

Below is the userprofile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['user']; //retrieve the session variable

?>
    <center><h1>User Profile </h1></center>
    <br/>
    <b>Welcome <?php
echo $user ?> </b>
    <div style="text-align: right"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div> <!-- 
    calling Logout.php to destroy the session -->
    <?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) //If user is not logged in then he cannot
accesstheprofilepage
    {

    // echo 'You are not logged in. <a href="login.php">Click here</a> to log

    in .;
    header("location:LoginForm.php");
    }

?>
```

You can try the login form at [test.laveshpillay.com/LoginForm.php][1]

You can type in any values and it will take you to the loading screen without validating and it will just stay on the **login.php** form

Let me know if you need any other parts of the code.

Comment: It seems simple. Your HTML form specifies a POST. So login data is sent via POST. But on your login.php you try to get your data via GET. Change that to POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following in your `login.php` file and try:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){//Made change here   
  use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`.
  //Your logic comes here.
}
?>
```

Comment: Also all `$_GET` need to be change to `$_POST`

Comment: Quick Question, @KetanSolanki Must I add this line  use     `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` or just change all $_GET to $_REQUEST

Comment: @LaveshPillay , See `$_REQUEST` get the data from `$_POST` as well as `$_GET`. So its better practice to use `$_REQUEST`.And Just replace all occurence of `$_GET` with `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I tried that but it still gets stuck at the test.laveshpillay.com/login.php screen and doesnt go anywhere from there

Comment: @LaveshPillay are you getting any errror?

Comment: Does this statement gets printed "Incorrect username or password" ?

Comment: @KetanSolanki it just goes to a white screen, and in the url i can see it is stuck at login.php

Comment: @LaveshPillay Then you have to debug it by yourself. Try adding `echo "abc123";` after every line so that you can know from where the page execution stops.\